# OpenGL ES Full Screen on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm just translating some bitmaps on the screen. When it's on my phone it looks fine, but when I try to run it on my tablet it looks like it's confined to a screen the size of my phone (roughly). Obviously I want it to scale to the screen size, what am I doing wrong here? I've attached some code and here's a screenshot of what's happening (I've made the background red so it's easy to see what I'm talking about). Thanks!

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {       
    //Settings
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);                    //Enable Texture Mapping
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);                    //Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);            //Black Background
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                             //Depth Buffer Setup

    //Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);                         //Enable blending
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);                   //Disable depth test
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE);     //Set The Blending Function For Translucency        

    //Initiate our stars class with the number of stars
    stars = new Stars(num);
    //Load the texture for the stars once during Surface creation
    stars.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    /*if(height == 0) {                         //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
    }*/

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix


    //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Modelview Matrix
}
```

If you need any other code please ask, I assume my problem is somewhere there.

Here's the screenshot [image]

Comment: There is no layout code. It's just drawing on the surface.

Comment: Well how do you create that surface then?

Comment: Looks like a layout issue to me, too.

Comment: Post your activity's onCreate method so we can see how you are creating the layout/surface